# Passing array as argument to a js function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanted to create a basic function summing up values from an array. I'm aware of the array reduce method but i wanted initially to use a loop "for" instead as below...however it returns NaN...why ?

```
var numbers=[1,2];
var total;
function sum(array){
   total=0;
   for(var x=0;x<=array.length;x++){    
    total += array[x];
   }
   return total;
}
```

Comment: `x<=array.length` ==> `x < array.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get NAN because, as the loop's condition is`x<=array.length`, the last iteration adds `array[length]` to the sum, while the last item of the array is `array[length - 1]`

Answer (score 1):

Do `sum(numbers)`, also in your loop the break condition should be `x<array.length;` also you do not need to make `total` a global variable to continue adding values of array to it.

```js
var numbers = [1, 2];

function sum(array) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
    total += array[x];
  }
  return total;
}

var total = sum(numbers);
alert(total);
```

Though the shorter way will be to use [**.reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on the array

```js
var array = [1,2]
var sum = array.reduce(function(prev, curr) { return prev + curr; }, 0);
alert(sum);
```

Here You can also provide an **[Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)** instead of a full function.

```js
var array = [1, 2]
var sum = array.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr);
alert(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum up all elements:

```
sum = array.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay on your initial approach, then you don't have to return global variable from within function. You can change global variables inside function directly;

```
var numbers=[1,2],
    total;
function sum(array){
   total=0;
   for(var x = 0, len = array.length; x < len; x++){    
    total += array[x];
   }
}
```

In other cases, of course, using of local variables is preferable when you  intend to form independent results